# Pandas : new column with index of unique values of another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My dataframe:

```
ID       Name_Identify  ColumnA  ColumnB  ColumnC
1        POM-OPP        D43      D03      D59
2        MIAN-ERP       D80      D74      E34
3        POM-OPP        E97      B56      A01
4        POM-OPP        A66      D04      C34
5        DONP28         B55      A42      A80
6        MIAN-ERP       E97      D59      C34
```

Expected new dataframe:

```
ID       Name_Identify ColumnA  ColumnB  ColumnC    NEW_ID
1        POM-OPP       D43      D03      D59        1
2        MIAN-ERP      D80      D74      E34        2
3        POM-OPP       E97      B56      A01        1
4        POM-OPP       A66      D04      C34        1
5        DONP28        B55      A42      A80        3
6        MIAN-ERP      E97      D59      C34        2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
convert = {k: v for v, k in enumerate(df.Name_Identify.unique(), start=1)}
df["NEW_ID"] = df.Name_Identify.map(convert)
```

---

*The explanation:*

In the first command we select *unique names* from the `Name_Identify` column

```
In[23]: df.Name_Identify.unique()
```

> ```
> array(['POM-OPP', 'MIAN-ERP', 'DONP28'], dtype=object)
> ```

and then create a dictionary from the *enumerated sequence of them* (the enumeration starts with `1`):

```
In[24]: convert = {k: v for v, k in enumerate(df.Name_Identify.unique(), start=1)}
In[25]: convert
```

> ```
> {'POM-OPP': 1, 'MIAN-ERP': 2, 'DONP28': 3}
> ```

In the second command *we use this dictionary* for creating a new column by *converting all names in the `Name_Identify` column to appropriate numbers:*

```
In[26]: df["NEW_ID"] = df.Name_Identify.map(convert)
In[27]: df
```

> ```
>    D Name_Identify ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC  NEW_ID
> 0  1       POM-OPP     D43     D03     D59       1
> 1  2      MIAN-ERP     D80     D74     E34       2
> 2  3       POM-OPP     E97     B56     A01       1
> 3  4       POM-OPP     A66     D04     C34       1
> 4  5        DONP28     B55     A42     A80       3
> 5  6      MIAN-ERP     E97     D59     C34       2
> ```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pandas.Categorical`:

```
df["NEW_ID"] = pd.Categorical(df["Name_Identify"], ordered=False).codes + 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pandas.groupby`:

```
df['NEW_ID'] = df.groupby('Name_Identify', sort=False).ngroup() + 1
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   ID Name_Identify ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC  NEW_ID
0   1       POM-OPP     D43     D03     D59       1
1   2      MIAN-ERP     D80     D74     E34       2
2   3       POM-OPP     E97     B56     A01       1
3   4       POM-OPP     A66     D04     C34       1
4   5        DONP28     B55     A42     A80       3
5   6      MIAN-ERP     E97     D59     C34       2
```